# SSL Cloudflare - www to non-www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, cloudflare

I am having the following issues with the Cloudflare Flexible SSL (Always use HTTPS, Automatic HTTPS rewrites activated)

**Before** activating the Cloudflare SSL the website in question nicely redirected from 
http://www.example.com to http://example.com same goes for 
www.example.com to example.com

**After** the Cloudflare SSL activation when I type in the I the following into the address bar:
example.com > https://example.com (green lock)
http://example.com > https://example.com (green lock)
www.example.com > https://example.com (css, js, certain images are not loading, gray lock with yellow triangle in address bar - mixed content)
http://www.example.com > https://www.example.com (css, js, certain images are not loading, gray lock with yellow triangle in address bar - mixed content)

Can someone let me know where to start to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the Cloudflare SSL mixed content issues has been resolved. I found a hard coded wrong base url in the html code